# TwoWay Binding не работает через DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

При изменении свойства через TwoWay binding не производится работа с переменной, только со свойством зависимости.

Отметил в коде комментариями нужные места.

Пути обхода я знаю (самый явный - через PropertyChanged), но неужели всё так плохо?

#### Вопрос, собственно, в том, как *просто* сделать двухсторонний binding?

Проект здесь: https://yadi.sk/d/ioEe0PZ2v7pEC

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SampleProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Sample" Height="100" Width="500">
    <UniformGrid Columns="1" Margin="5">

        <!-- Привязка на следующей строке НЕ вызовет setter переменной SliderValue -->
        <Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>

    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace SampleProject
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SliderValue = 3.123456789; // <<== Это вызовет setter переменной SliderValue
        }

        // ==>> TextBlock.Text
        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(_propTextValue); }
            set { SetValue(_propTextValue, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty _propTextValue =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextValue", typeof(string),
            typeof(MainWindow),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Ожидание значения..."));

        // ==>> Slider.Value
        public double SliderValue
        {
            get
            { return (double) GetValue(_propSliderValue); }
            set
            {
                TextValue = value.ToString();
                SetValue(_propSliderValue, value);
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty _propSliderValue =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SliderValue", typeof(double),
            typeof(MainWindow),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(5.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы нарушили контракт для DependencyProperty: ваши `static`-поля должны называться `TextValueProperty` и `SliderValueProperty` соответственно (а не `_propTextValue` и `_propSliderValue`).

Переименуйте.

Кроме того, вы почему-то надеетесь, что ваш setter будет вызываться WPF-фреймворком. Нет, это тоже не гарантировано. Связывать dependency property нужно через property change callback:

```
public double SliderValue
{
    get { return (double) GetValue(SliderValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SliderValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SliderValue",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(MainWindow),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            5.0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            OnSliderChange));

static void OnSliderChange(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var self = (MainWindow)o;
    self.TextValue = args.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

Ну или немного проще:

```
public double SliderValue
{
    get { return (double) GetValue(SliderValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SliderValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SliderValue",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(MainWindow),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            5.0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            (o, args) => o.SetValue(TextValueProperty, args.NewValue.ToString()));
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию об именовании - MSDN это настоятельно рекомендует. Но вопрос не решился. И пути обхода я, конечно, понимаю. Но когда интерфейс сложный, и не всегда заранее ясна взаимосвязь переменных, то рекомендованный Вами подход неэффективен.

Comment: @ZloyMakak: Пожалуйста! Отпишитесь по результатам.

Comment: @ZloyMakak: Эээ, подход-то может и неэффективен, но ничего другого у вас нет. Вызов сеттера не гарантирован (и чаще всего будет проигнорирован). Ну и я не вижу проблемы эффективности: если у вас сложные вычисления, то вы их должны всё равно делать в модели, а не в UI.

Comment: Да я знаю про пути обхода. Но как же не хочется признавать правильным решением этот механизм. Но я уже весь интернет перерыл - люди как-то с этим живут...

Comment: «Нет, это тоже не гарантировано» — а разве не гарантировано обратное? Насколько я помню, если источником изменений является XAML, то `SetValue` всегда вызывается напрямую

Comment: @ZloyMakak, используйту [`INPC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) и не будете иметь всей этой писанины, что требует `DP`.  `DP` нужны для контролов, для «простых смертных» они не нужны.

Comment: @ixSci: Вот этого не знаю. Например, если XAML не сможет определить, что перед ним DP, он ведь полезет за setter'ом? Может быть, в каких-то хитрых ситуациях он проваливается в эту логику и с DP.

Comment: Смотрите. DP нужны для свойств контрола (соответствующих разным аспектам визуализации). Для логических свойств нужно INPC. Но логическим свойствам вовсе не место в контроле, им место в VM. Поэтому если вам нужна сложная логика, вы делаете неправильно.

Comment: @ixSci: Я на самом деле пишу usercontrol (Slider с возможностью задавать диапазон). Там свойства перекрёстно завязаны друг на друга. Просто сам вопрос был в том, можно ли не задействовать механизм вручную прописанных событий для twoway байндинга. Оказалось, что нет. Контрол доделал, захотите - выложу здесь апдейтом.